# How can i achieve bi-directional calender integration between o365 & ServiceNow?

Tags: email, outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I have a requirement for one of the projects where we need to integrate outlook/exchange calendar with ServiceNow bi-directional fashion.

1) So if there's an event created in a user's calendar in outlook it should go to ServiceNow and create a record or something similar.

2) If I create a record for a user in ServiceNow it should be added to the user's calendar in Outlook/Exchange account.

Basically you can say that I want calendar sync from both the sources and both of them should reflect the same calendar.

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Graph has change notifications (webhooks) that allow you to subscribe to events to a particular mailbox which includes a calendar.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

This would satisfy any events that get created in Office 365 notifying your own API service that could then call the Service NOw API to create/update the event.

I'm assuming Service Now also has web hooks for their calendar so you could do it in the other direction.